# Does the order of querystring in url affects seo (duplicate content)?

Tags: url, seo, query-string

Does the order of querystring affects seo (duplicate content)?

is a page index.php?a=1&b=2 considered a duplicate of index.php?b=2&a=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you serve the same content on the pages then it would be duplicate content. You can set canonical tags to point to the preferred version of the page for indexing :http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: so order does matter?

Comment: A different order would make a different url, and so if they serve the same content - you need to look into canonical tags.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it does not make a difference to SEO.

Order for URL query parameters does not matter and all URL libraries that I know do not order query params in no sense, therefore it would not make sense for SEO engines to differentiate between cases `?a=1&b=2`

On the other hand, for completeness, the order of URL path segments matters and these would have a different effect on SEO:
`/shoes/Abibas` vs `Abibas/shoes`

Comment: I tend to agree with you, however 'it would not make sense' is one of the worst IT mantra that ironically happens be wrong when you least expect it!
 
It is true that URL libraries usually parse the query string as an unordered collection but have you got anything to support your claim that search engine do the same? As the page content is technically duplicated, only one URL will appear on the SERP but how to determine which one without canonical URL?